# How to import xls column with postal codes as character, not numeric

Tags: r, dplyr, readxl

I have a excel sheet with US states and their Postal codes, when I import the file with `read_xls` function the Postal codes are coerced into numbers and codes which have `0` starting of the code are gone. Ex: Code of Vermont is `05408` after the import it coerces it into `5408` this happened 11 times in the data frame, I cannot import as text because then all the dates in data frame would be converted into numbers, which I don't want happening.

I tried to add `0` infront of the code by using the function

```
crrt_postcode <- function(`Postal Code`){
case_when(nchar(`Postal Code`) == 4 ~ paste0('0', `Postal Code`),
    TRUE ~ as.character(`Postal Code`)
  )
}
```

BUt this did not work, Is there anything else I can do to fix this?

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example

Comment: As `?read_xls` explains, you can specify a *vector* of data types in `col_types` argument. So specify "numeric" for numeric columns and "text" for postal code and other character columns.

Comment: Try this: `sapply(`Postal Code`, function(x){if(nchar(x)==5){paste0(0,x)}else{x}})`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using

```
library(dplyr)

crrt_postcode <- function(`Postal Code`) {
  case_when(
    nchar(`Postal Code`) == 4 ~ paste0('0', `Postal Code`),
    TRUE ~ as.character(`Postal Code`)
  )
}
```

and the `mutate` function:

```
sample_store_1 <- sample_store %>%
  mutate(`Postal Code` =  crrt_postcode(`Postal Code`))
```